# Deducing angle in equilateral triangle by the formula $\phi_2 = \alpha - \phi_1$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, physics

I have the following equilateral triangle:

[image]

In the following picture of the same equilateral triangle, the dotted lines are the normals to the surfaces:

[image]

Since this is an equilateral triangle, we know that the three angles are $60^\circ$. And the since the dashed lines are normal to the surfaces of the triangle, we know that the angle they make with the triangle surface is $90^\circ$.

Furthermore, thanks to David K's excellent answer in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3421081/356308) question, we can find the angle $19.5^\circ$ by using "alternate angles":

[image]

I've now been trying to figure out how the angle $40.5^\circ$ was found. From there, we can use [Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell's_law) to find the angle $77.1^\circ$.

According to [this](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Optics/Book%3A_Geometric_Optics_(Tatum)/1%3A_Reflection_and_Refraction/1.6%3A_Refraction_by_a_Prism) website, the angle $40.5$ is found by $\phi_2 = \alpha - \phi_1$ in the following image:

[image]

This computation gives us $\phi_2 = 60^\circ - 19.5^\circ = 40.5^\circ$, as required.

However, the website does not tell us *where* the formula $\phi_2 = \alpha - \phi_1$ came from - it just states that it is found by geometry.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain where $\phi_2 = \alpha - \phi_1$ came from; in other words, what it is called, how it was derived, the geometric reasoning behind it, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note

$$\phi_1+x=90,\>\>\>\>\>\phi_2+y=90$$

$$x+y+\alpha=180$$

Eliminate $x$ and $y$ to get $\phi_1+\phi_2=\alpha$.

[image]